# Use same configuration in multiple subdirectories cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project with a bunch of subdirectories, all of which I want compiled essentially the same way (the subdirectories are essentially separate projects themselves, they just have similar configurations).
The root CMakeLists.txt looks something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/path/to/arm-toolchain.cmake")
project(Examples)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-error")

include_directories("path/to/include")
link_directories("path/to/lib")

add_subdirectory(Foo)
add_subdirectory(Bar)
add_subdirectory(Bob)
add_subdirectory(Encoder)
```

And in each subdirectory, I have a CMakeLists.txt something like:

```
# Use subdirectory name for executable name.
get_filename_component(OutName ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
string(REPLACE " " "_" OutName ${OutName})
file(GLOB Source "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(${OutName} ${Source})
target_link_libraries(${OutName} libtolink)
```

And the contents of the individual subdirectory CMakeLists.txt's are identical for every subdirectory. Is there any way from within cmake to avoid having to copy the CMakeLists.txt for every subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a function in the parent CMakeLists.txt file:

```
function(subproject subdir)
  # Use subdirectory name for executable name.
  get_filename_component(OutName ${subdir} NAME)
  string(REPLACE " " "_" OutName ${OutName})
  file(GLOB Source "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${subdir}/src/*.cpp")

  add_executable(${OutName} ${Source})
  target_link_libraries(${OutName} libtolink)
  set_property(
    TARGET ${OutName}
    PROPERTY RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${subdir}"
  ) # write the compiled program in the subdirectory
endfunction()
```

and call it for every subproject, instead of `add_subdirectory`:

```
subproject(Foo)
subproject(Bar)
subproject(Bob)
subproject(Encoder)
```

Comment: That worked; I didn't realize at first that I no longer needed to call add_subdirectory on each subdirectory, and personally I commented out the set_property(TARGET..... line because I didn't want/need it, but beyond those quirks that you couldn't've been aware if, it worked.

Comment: yes, I tried to emulate the "add_subdirectory" behaviour of writing binaries in the subdirectory, but if you don't need that, that just makes the whole thing simpler !